# Cannot find certain packages to install in Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, dnf

I want to install the wizardpen driver (Generic linux driver for pen-tablets) from source on Fedora 22.
Upon attempting the install from source after downloading, it threw the following error about library dependencies:

```
No package 'xorg-server' found
No package 'xproto' found
```

I tried to search for the package xorg-server to install it with the following command:

```
sudo dnf search 'xorg-server'
```

However, it threw this error:

```
Error: No matches found.
```

The same thing happened with the package xproto. I am stuck without any clue. Please suggest how I can proceed with installing the 2 libraries 'xorg-server' and 'xproto' in Fedora, so that I can try installing the wizardpen driver from source.

Comment: Fedora 22 is EOL and the packages might be gone from the mirrors. Update to current version to get a new packages and updates

Comment: That is not the case. The package names I got from the error message were not the exact ones. Please see the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered by SteveGYBE on FedoraForum.
The packages I was looking for were actually named:

- xorg-x11-proto-devel
- xorg-x11-server-devel

These provide the files "/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/xproto.pc" and "/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/xorg-server.pc" that the "pkg-config" program will be looking for.
The fix was to run:

```
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-proto-devel
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-server-devel
```